# mvc4 dropdownlistfor value not populated in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page where I want a dropdown list that contains choices of roles (ex R1, R2, R3): the user will choose the role they want in the dropdown.

I have a view model with a int RoleId property which should contain the id of the role that the user has selected. I set the RoleId to a default value of 1 . Also on the view model, I create a SelectList that has list of role choices.

The view renders fine - the role choices are all in the dropdown, the one I specified by setting RoleId is already selected.

Then I choose a different role from the dropdown and post the form.

When I check the value of the RoleId on the model it is still set to the original choice, not the changed value. So for example in the code below I set the RoleId=1, and then change it to 2 by selecting from the dropdown in the view, and post. The model that comes back in the post action is has a RoleId=1

```
    public class CreateUserViewModel
        {   
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "User Name")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }

public ActionResult Create()
            {
   var model = new CreateUserViewModel()
   model.RoleId=1;
   return View(model);
}

     [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
            {
// RoleId=1 here, but should be 2
}
```

In the view I have the following

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RolesList)
```

I have even tried adding an extra line that I have seen in some answers:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RoleId)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: im confused,  you say that you create your List<SelectListItem> in your view model but the code you have posted shows you passing that list through the viewbag.  Look at the values on the rendered drop down.  Are the values of the options different?

Comment: All you want is a DropDown list that gets populated in controller and in your view you will choose a option and the respective Id will be posted back to controller , Right?

Comment: Correct ready. And im getting a value, but it's the value that was in the view originally, rather than changed value from changing the selected option in the drodown

Comment: Matt, sorry I typed view model instead of view bag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I removed the

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RoleId)
```

it began working